# Can Scala Option class be used as a function argument?

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a recursive function which collects the leaf nodes of a kd-tree. This function has to take KdNode as an argument. The KdNode has the following class definition:

```
case class KdNode(value: (Double, Double), left: Option[KdNode], right: Option[KdNode], axis: Int, BB_A:BoundingBox, BB_B:BoundingBox)
```

The function definition where it is taken as an argument is:

```
def collectLeafNodes(t:KdNode): List[BoundingBox] = {
if(t == None) return
if (t.left == None && t.right == None) {
  Some(listBoundingBox.::(t.BB_A,t.BB_B))
  return
}
collectLeafNodes(t.left)
collectLeafNodes(t.right)}
```

Here, I encounter error on the last 2 lines saying: "Type mismatch, expected: KdNode, actual: Option[KdNode].

I am calling this function by building the kd-tree in variable "tree" and giving it as an argument:

```
val listofBoundingBoxes=collectLeafNodes(tree)
```

What is a possible workaround in this situation? In addition, I think there should be a way to pass the root node instead of tree to the collectLeafNodes function, is that possible given the tree is built in a separate function.

Thanks.

Comment: Its about your method `def collectLeafNodes(t:KdNode): List[BoundingBox]` which means that this method will take a `t` which must be `KdNode`. It will not accept anything which is not a KdNode.

Comment: Don't use `return` in Scala code. It will (and already has) lead you astray.

Comment: also do not do `t == None`. Use `t.isEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, but what can be used instead of return?

Comment: @Sarvesh, pls can you tell how can I call this function from the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask, in the comments, how it can be done without `return`. Here's one way.

```
def collectLeafNodes(t :KdNode) :List[BoundingBox] =
  List(t.BB_A, t.BB_B) :::
    t.left.fold(List.empty[BoundingBox])(collectLeafNodes) :::
    t.right.fold(List.empty[BoundingBox])(collectLeafNodes)
```

The result, without `return`, is the concatenation of 3 lists:

1. Since `t` is a `KdNode` and not an `Option[KdNode]`, we know that the the `BB` values are real. That's the 1st `List`.
2. If `t.left` is `None` then the 2nd `List` is empty, otherwise the 2nd `List` is whatever the recursive call to `collectLeafNodes(t.left)` returns. (The argument is automatically supplied so it need not be specified.)
3. Same for the 3rd `List` with `t.right`

---

**corrected for leaf nodes only**

```
def collectLeafNodes(t :KdNode) :List[BoundingBox] = {
  if (t.left.isEmpty && t.right.isEmpty) List(t.BB_A, t.BB_B)
  else t.left .fold(List.empty[BoundingBox])(collectLeafNodes) :::
       t.right.fold(List.empty[BoundingBox])(collectLeafNodes)
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. However, this gives the bounding boxes of all nodes, not just the leaves :)

Answer (score 2):

You can map over the option object:

```
val res: List[BoundingBox] = t.left.map(collectLeafNodes).getOrElse(List())
```

Answer (score 0):

Because t.right is type of Option and not type of Kdnode.

You can unwrap Option to solve this  e.g.

```
collectLeafNodes(t.right.get)}
collectLeafNodes(t.right.orElse(None)}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't use `.get`. It's a code smell. And `.orElse(None)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ Brian McCutchon Agree with you. Above was just illustration to  unwrap option.